# tempfile python3 do not have read/write permission on EFS (AWS EC2 instance)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

I'm creating a tempfile on the EFS on AWS EC2 Instance. But It do not have read/write permission on the EFS with root user. If I create the tempfile using the home/ubuntu user it do have read/write permission. Please let me know if anybody knows the reason.
Here is my code snippet.

1- code snippet to create the tempfile

```
temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.zip', delete=True, dir=join(abspath('./'), "temp"))
    temp_file.write(file.stream.read())
```

2 - Providing this tempfile path, I'm reading the tempfile and unzipping this in some another directory. But it's giving me error as File do not have read/write permission

```
@staticmethod
def unzip_shp_zip_file(zip_file_path):
    unzip_file_path = TemporaryDirectory(dir=join(abspath('./'), "temp")).name
    try:
        with ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
            zip_ref.extractall(unzip_file_path)

    except BadZipfile:
        Utility.___logger.error("Unable to Unzip {} :".format(zip_file_path))
        traceback.print_stack()

    return unzip_file_path
```